Given $P(A^c)=a$ and $P(B^c)=b$, show that $P(A\cap B)=1-a-b$
There's no additional information about hte relation of the sets. That's all. Can you give me some ideas??
Let $P(A^c)=a$ and $P(B^c)=b$, then $P(A)=1-a$ and $P(B)=1-b$. Now,
$$P(A\cap B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cup B)$$
so, $P(A\cap B)=(1-a)+(1-b)-P(A\cup B)=2-a-b-P(A\cup B)$
Does $P(A\cup B)=1$?

That's obviously false. If $A=B=\emptyset$ then $P(A^c)=1$, $P(B^c)=1$, so $1-a-b = -1$ can't be the probability of $P(A\cap B) = P(\emptyset)$.

This is the fullest information we can get from the proposed relations:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(A\cap B) & = 1 - \mathbb{P}((A\cap B)^{c})\\
& = 1 - \mathbb{P}(A^{c}\cup B^{c})\\
& = 1 - (\mathbb{P}(A^{c}) + \mathbb{P}(B^{c}) - \mathbb{P}(A^{c}\cap B^{c}))\\
& = 1 - a - b + \mathbb{P}(A^{c}\cap B^{c})
\end{align*}
The proposed relation holds if $A^{c}$ and $B^{c}$ are mutually exclusive.
Hopefully this helps!
